# Heroku ' We're sorry, but something went wrong.'[rails 4]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

If you check out the app I'm working out below you'll see that when you click 'more' the Page just keeps loading. Also when you go to comment you get the Heroku 'We're sorry, but something went wrong.' error.

Bare in mind, the app was working just before I did a new push after having added YouTube integration and having a S.O friend help me with adding Tags.

The app: www.leapfm.com

**Heroku logs:**

```
[leap_stage_v2]$heroku logs
2013-08-03T01:20:45.858331+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-08-03T01:20:45.858331+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start'
2013-08-03T01:20:45.858521+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `require'
2013-08-03T01:20:45.858521+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-08-03 01:20:45] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2013-08-03T01:20:45.858521+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-08-03 01:20:45] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2013-08-03T01:20:45.858764+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2013-08-03T01:20:47.918851+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2013-08-03T01:20:50.398732+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 59930 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-08-03T01:20:59.192158+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-08-03 01:20:59] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-08-03T01:20:59.192158+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-08-03 01:20:59] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-linux]
2013-08-03T01:20:59.192667+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-08-03 01:20:59] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=59930
2013-08-03T01:20:59.258213+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-08-03T01:21:00.619163+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2013-08-03T01:21:00.619163+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-08-03T01:21:00.618960 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/new_songs" for 99.233.170.104 at 2013-08-03 01:21:00 +0000
2013-08-03T01:21:00.619163+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-08-03T01:21:00.619163+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-08-03T01:21:00.619163+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.0.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:59930
2013-08-03T01:21:00.619163+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-08-03T01:21:00.619049 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/new_songs" for 99.233.170.104 at 2013-08-03 01:21:00 +0000
2013-08-03T01:21:01.909288+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/new_songs host=serene-dawn-9638.herokuapp.com fwd="99.233.170.104" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=1325ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-08-03T01:21:02.052430+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-554af6199e8ee1a22f5fe52a203f638e.css host=serene-dawn-9638.herokuapp.com fwd="99.233.170.104" dyno=web.1 connect=8ms service=15ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-08-03T01:21:02.251487+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=serene-dawn-9638.herokuapp.com fwd="99.233.170.104" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=1150
2013-08-03T01:23:19.668912+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-08-03T01:23:19.668726 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/new_songs" for 99.233.170.104 at 2013-08-03 01:23:19 +0000
2013-08-03T01:23:19.668912+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-08-03T01:23:19.668807 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/new_songs" for 99.233.170.104 at 2013-08-03 01:23:19 +0000
2013-08-03T01:23:19.838740+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/new_songs host=serene-dawn-9638.herokuapp.com fwd="99.233.170.104" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=176ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-08-03T01:23:20.060966+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=serene-dawn-9638.herokuapp.com fwd="99.233.170.104" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=9ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-08-03T01:23:22.233526+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-08-03T01:23:22.233350 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/new_songs" for 99.233.170.104 at 2013-08-03 01:23:22 +0000
2013-08-03T01:23:22.233526+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-08-03T01:23:22.233418 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/new_songs" for 99.233.170.104 at 2013-08-03 01:23:22 +0000
2013-08-03T01:23:22.428713+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/new_songs host=serene-dawn-9638.herokuapp.com fwd="99.233.170.104" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=204ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-08-03T01:23:25.608466+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-08-03T01:23:25.608292 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/new_songs?page=2&_=1375493002486" for 99.233.170.104 at 2013-08-03 01:23:25 +0000
2013-08-03T01:23:25.608628+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-08-03T01:23:25.608512 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/new_songs?page=2&_=1375493002486" for 99.233.170.104 at 2013-08-03 01:23:25 +0000
2013-08-03T01:23:25.781320+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/new_songs?page=2&_=1375493002486 host=serene-dawn-9638.herokuapp.com fwd="99.233.170.104" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=181ms status=200 bytes=4862
2013-08-03T01:23:32.001826+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-08-03T01:23:32.001660 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 99.233.170.104 at 2013-08-03 01:23:32 +0000
2013-08-03T01:23:32.001826+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-08-03T01:23:32.001730 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 99.233.170.104 at 2013-08-03 01:23:32 +0000
2013-08-03T01:23:33.081695+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=serene-dawn-9638.herokuapp.com fwd="99.233.170.104" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1092ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-08-03T01:23:34.122629+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-08-03T01:23:34.122452 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/songs/new" for 99.233.170.104 at 2013-08-03 01:23:34 +0000
2013-08-03T01:23:34.122629+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-08-03T01:23:34.122522 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/songs/new" for 99.233.170.104 at 2013-08-03 01:23:34 +0000
2013-08-03T01:23:34.176035+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/songs/new host=serene-dawn-9638.herokuapp.com fwd="99.233.170.104" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=59ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-08-03T01:23:35.787386+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-08-03T01:23:35.787271 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 99.233.170.104 at 2013-08-03 01:23:35 +0000
2013-08-03T01:23:35.787386+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-08-03T01:23:35.787201 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 99.233.170.104 at 2013-08-03 01:23:35 +0000
2013-08-03T01:23:36.239851+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=serene-dawn-9638.herokuapp.com fwd="99.233.170.104" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=467ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-08-03T01:23:37.794481+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-08-03T01:23:37.794310 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/songs?page=2&_=1375493016363" for 99.233.170.104 at 2013-08-03 01:23:37 +0000
2013-08-03T01:23:37.794481+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-08-03T01:23:37.794380 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/songs?page=2&_=1375493016363" for 99.233.170.104 at 2013-08-03 01:23:37 +0000
2013-08-03T01:23:37.907992+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/app/views"
2013-08-03T01:23:37.907992+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial songs/new_songs, application/new_songs with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, "application/ecmascript", "application/x-ecmascript", :html, :text, :css, :ics, :csv, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
2013-08-03T01:23:37.907992+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2013-08-03T01:23:37.907817 #2] FATAL -- : 
2013-08-03T01:23:37.907992+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0.rc/app/views"
2013-08-03T01:23:37.907992+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2013-08-03T01:23:37.907992+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: $("#new_songs").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("new_songs")) %>");
2013-08-03T01:23:37.907992+00:00 app[web.1]:     4: 
2013-08-03T01:23:37.907992+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:  
2013-08-03T01:23:37.908278+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/songs/index.js.erb:3:in `_app_views_songs_index_js_erb___1053151595308596002_69829959927520'
2013-08-03T01:23:37.908278+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-08-03T01:23:37.908278+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-08-03T01:23:37.908278+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial songs/new_songs, application/new_songs with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, "application/ecmascript", "application/x-ecmascript", :html, :text, :css, :ics, :csv, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
2013-08-03T01:23:37.908278+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/app/views"
2013-08-03T01:23:37.907992+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: $("#songs").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("songs")) %>");
2013-08-03T01:23:37.907992+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: 
2013-08-03T01:23:37.908278+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2013-08-03T01:23:37.907891 #2] FATAL -- : 
2013-08-03T01:23:37.908447+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: $("#new_songs").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("new_songs")) %>");
2013-08-03T01:23:37.908278+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2013-08-03T01:23:37.908278+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: $("#songs").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("songs")) %>");
2013-08-03T01:23:37.908447+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-08-03T01:23:37.908447+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-08-03T01:23:37.908447+00:00 app[web.1]:     4: 
2013-08-03T01:23:37.908278+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: 
2013-08-03T01:23:37.908447+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/songs/index.js.erb:3:in `_app_views_songs_index_js_erb___1053151595308596002_69829959927520'
2013-08-03T01:23:37.908278+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0.rc/app/views"
2013-08-03T01:23:37.908447+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:  
2013-08-03T01:23:37.910294+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/songs?page=2&_=1375493016363 host=serene-dawn-9638.herokuapp.com fwd="99.233.170.104" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=124ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-08-03T01:23:43.370609+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-08-03T01:23:43.370446 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 99.233.170.104 at 2013-08-03 01:23:43 +0000
2013-08-03T01:23:43.370609+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-08-03T01:23:43.370509 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 99.233.170.104 at 2013-08-03 01:23:43 +0000
2013-08-03T01:23:43.746652+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=serene-dawn-9638.herokuapp.com fwd="99.233.170.104" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=387ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-08-03T01:23:45.858423+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-08-03T01:23:45.858306 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/songs?page=2&_=1375493023938" for 99.233.170.104 at 2013-08-03 01:23:45 +0000
2013-08-03T01:23:45.858506+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-08-03T01:23:45.858423 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/songs?page=2&_=1375493023938" for 99.233.170.104 at 2013-08-03 01:23:45 +0000
2013-08-03T01:23:45.925390+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2013-08-03T01:23:45.924890 #2] FATAL -- : 
2013-08-03T01:23:45.925390+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial songs/new_songs, application/new_songs with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, "application/ecmascript", "application/x-ecmascript", :html, :text, :css, :ics, :csv, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
2013-08-03T01:23:45.925390+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/app/views"
2013-08-03T01:23:45.925390+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2013-08-03T01:23:45.925390+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: $("#songs").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("songs")) %>");
2013-08-03T01:23:45.925390+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: 
2013-08-03T01:23:45.925390+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: $("#new_songs").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("new_songs")) %>");
2013-08-03T01:23:45.925390+00:00 app[web.1]:     4: 
2013-08-03T01:23:45.925390+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:  
2013-08-03T01:23:45.925622+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/songs/index.js.erb:3:in `_app_views_songs_index_js_erb___1053151595308596002_69829959927520'
2013-08-03T01:23:45.925622+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-08-03T01:23:45.925622+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2013-08-03T01:23:45.925622+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0.rc/app/views"
2013-08-03T01:23:45.925390+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0.rc/app/views"
2013-08-03T01:23:45.925622+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: $("#songs").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("songs")) %>");
2013-08-03T01:23:45.925622+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: 
2013-08-03T01:23:45.925622+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial songs/new_songs, application/new_songs with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, "application/ecmascript", "application/x-ecmascript", :html, :text, :css, :ics, :csv, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
2013-08-03T01:23:45.925622+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-08-03T01:23:45.925801+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:  
2013-08-03T01:23:45.925622+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2013-08-03T01:23:45.925296 #2] FATAL -- : 
2013-08-03T01:23:45.925622+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/app/views"
2013-08-03T01:23:45.925801+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: $("#new_songs").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("new_songs")) %>");
2013-08-03T01:23:45.925801+00:00 app[web.1]:     4: 
2013-08-03T01:23:45.925801+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/songs/index.js.erb:3:in `_app_views_songs_index_js_erb___1053151595308596002_69829959927520'
2013-08-03T01:23:45.925801+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-08-03T01:23:45.925443+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/songs?page=2&_=1375493023938 host=serene-dawn-9638.herokuapp.com fwd="99.233.170.104" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=78ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-08-03T01:23:45.925801+00:00 app[web.1]: 
[leap_stage_v2]$
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is included in the logs:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial songs/new_songs, application/new_songs with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, "application/ecmascript", "application/x-ecmascript", :html, :text, :css, :ics, :csv, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
```

Comment: I've fixed that now but if you go to New songs and click More it just keeps loading? I'll update the heroku logs with the new partial.